# C# SameSite attribute missing in HttpCookie dotnet 4.5.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, samesite

By recent updates in Google chrome. My website is not able to expire cookies on Google Chrome version 84.
getting following warning

[image]

As per some of my research, Cookie attribute **Secure** and **SameSite** needs to be updated with **false** and **None** respectively.

The problem is SameSite attribute is not available in c# dot net 4.5.2

```
HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(name);
cookie.Secure = true;
```

How can I achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Net library supports in Standard and non Standard HTTP headers.  For example UserAgent is a standard header while SameSite is non standard. So you need to add another header to your request.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a new unique hader to your request. When you use default header,browsers think to sending a same request to server. But when you give a unique header to your request your problem will solve. All requests will be different.

Look this codes, you can find more in [Set-Cookie Headers](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/29/SetCookie-Headers-getting-stripped-in-ASPNET-HttpHandlers).

```
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {                        
        HttpRequest request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        // If ClearHeaders is used Set-Cookie header gets removed!
        // if commented header is sent...
        response.ClearHeaders();

        response.ClearContent(); 
                            
        // Demonstrate that other headers make it
        response.AppendHeader("RequestId", "asdasdasd");
        
        // This cookie gets removed when ClearHeaders above is called
        // When ClearHEaders is omitted above the cookie renders
        response.AppendHeader("Set-Cookie", "WWTHREADSID=ThisIsThEValue; path=/");

       // *** This always works, even when explicit 
       //     Set-Cookie above fails and ClearHeaders is called
       //response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("WWTHREADSID", "ThisIsTheValue"));

        response.Write(@"Output was created.<hr/>
                       Check output…");            
    }
```

Comment: You can make it different ways, this code is just a simple example.